# Why does it not detect collision with the horizontal line to the left of the door

Tags: javascript, processing, collision, p5.js

I'm struggling with this code in JS P5. I'm trying to make collision detection with the lines. It works with the  vertical lines until I set the variable 'distance_3' after 'distances_2', after this it will not work. I have also problems to make detection collision with first Horizontally line. I don't know if this explanation of my issue is good enough, but if not, be sure to say!

Can somebody tell me why? Here are the lines of code that doesn't do what I want to happen.
The full code can be seen in this link https://editor.p5js.org/Mohammad/full/uzCnEN_oG

```
  function draw() 
  {
  background(220);
  for (let i = 0; i < listOfPeople.length; i++) {
    listOfPeople[i].setupHuman();
    listOfPeople[i].move();
    listOfPeople[i].drawer();

    for (let h = 0; h < listHouses.length; h++) {
      listHouses[h].draw_house();

      /* Distances for the vertical lines  */
      lengthOfVerticalLine = check_distance(
        listHouses[h].x_1,
        listHouses[h].x_1,
        listHouses[h].y_1,
        0
      );
      /* The Horizontally line left for the door */
      lengthOfHorizontalLine_1 = check_distance(
        listHouses[h].x_2,
        0,
        listHouses[h].y_1,
        listHouses[h].y_1
      );

      /* Circle left bottom */
      distance_1 = check_distance(
        listOfPeople[i].x,
        listHouses[h].x_1,
        listOfPeople[i].y,
        listHouses[h].y_1
      );

      /* Circle top left*/
      distance_2 = check_distance(
        listOfPeople[i].x,
        listHouses[h].x_1,
        listOfPeople[i].y,
        0
      );

      /* Circle left for the door */
      distance_3 = check_distance(
        listOfPeople[i].x,
        listHouses[h].x_2,
        listOfPeople[i].y,
        listHouses[h].y_1
      );

      /* Collision with the vertical line (Method: line segment) */
      if (
        distance_1 + distance_2 + listOfPeople[i].radius >=
          lengthOfVerticalLine - 40 &&
        distance_1 + distance_2 + listOfPeople[i].radius <=
          lengthOfVerticalLine + 40
      ) {
        if (listOfPeople[i].randomerX == -1) {
          listOfPeople[i].randomerX *= -1;
          listOfPeople[i].randomerY *= -1;
          listOfPeople[i].x += 3;
        } else if (listOfPeople[i].randomerX == 1) {
          listOfPeople[i].randomerX *= -1;
          listOfPeople[i].randomerY *= -1;
          listOfPeople[i].x -= 3;
        }
      }

      /* Collision with the first Horizontally line  */
      if (
        distance_2 + distance_3 + listOfPeople[i].radius >= 140 - 0.1 &&
        distance_2 + distance_3 + listOfPeople[i].radius <= 140 + 0.1
      ) {
        if (listOfPeople[i].randomerY == -1) {
          listOfPeople[i].randomerX *= -1;
          listOfPeople[i].randomerY *= -1;
          listOfPeople[i].y += 3;
        } else if (listOfPeople[i].randomerY == 1) {
          listOfPeople[i].randomerX *= -1;
          listOfPeople[i].randomerY *= -1;
          listOfPeople[i].y -= 3;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should add a method to the house class to check if a human touches its border.  This would simplify the algorithm.

Comment: Also don't draw the house inside the people loop.  The houses don't move.